# Template operator overload of template base class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having trouble calling a template assignment operator overload method, of a template base class. This is what I have so far:

BaseClass.h:

```
template<typename T>
class BaseClass
{
    template<typename U>
    BaseClass<T>& operator=(const BaseClass<U>& o)
    {
        return *this;
    };
};
```

ChildClassInt.h:

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
class ChildClassInt : public BaseClass<int>
{
};
```

ChildClassFloat.h:

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
class ChildClassFloat : public BaseClass<float>
{
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "ChildClassInt.h"
#include "ChildClassFloat.h"

int main()
{
    const ChildClassFloat floatClass;

    ChildClassInt intClass;

    return 0;
}
```

How do I call the `operator=()` method of `intClass` and pass it `floatClass`?

Comment: You probably meant `return *this;` I guess?

Comment: Your assignment operator does nothing.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for - `intClass.BaseClass<int>::operator=(floatClass);`?

Answer (score 1):

`intClass` always has an implicitly defined assignment operator, which always hides assignment operators from base classes. To explicitly call the base class assignment operator requires explicit qualification:

```
intClass.BaseClass<int>::operator=(floatClass);
```

(Note: Your code has two errors. First, `BaseClass<int>::operator=` is private. Second, it should return `*this`, not `this`.)

However, **you probably should not do this**. In general, assigning to a subobject can result in a broken complete object, since the base class assignment operator isn't aware of the derived class's invariants. If you really need to assign a `ChildClassFloat` to a `ChildClassInt`, you should define an assignment operator:

```
ChildClassInt& ChildClassInt::operator=(const ChildClassFloat& c) {
    BaseClass<int>::operator=(c);
    return *this;
}
```

Then the user can just do:

```
intClass = floatClass;
```

Since this assignment operator is part of the implementation of `ChildClassInt`, it knows how to perform the assignment in a way that preserves the invariants of `ChildClassInt` and will be updated if necessary when the implementation changes. The user, on the other hand, cannot be expected to know whether directly performing partial assignment to a base class will work, and, even if it does, the user code can be broken at any time by a change to the class implementation.